# How to make ball touch edge of window in Python?

Tags: python

I have this code for a ball bouncing on around the window. And, it doesn't touch 100% the edge of the window, but my teacher would like it to. How do you modify this? The ball also appears to be moving really fast so it doesn't even resemble a circle. Does anyone have any idea why this happening? Thank you.

```
from graphics import * #import graphics file
import time #import time module
from random import randrange
def main():
    win = GraphWin('Bouncing Ball', 500, 500) #create a window to draw upon
    x=randrange(50,450)
    y=randrange(50,450)
    a=1
    b=1

    circ1 = Circle(Point(x,y),10)
    circ1.setFill("green")
    circ1.draw(win)


    for i in range(2000): #"i" establishes the amount of time the stuff below runs for
        circ1.move(a,b)
        center = circ1.getCenter()
        x = center.getX()
        y = center.getY()
        if 500-(x+25)<1:
            z=randrange(1,4)
            if (a<0):
                a=-z
            else:
                a=z
                a=-a
            #to not alter speed use this as code instead:
            # a=-a
        elif x-25<1:
            z=randrange(1,4)
            if (a<0):
                a=z
            else:
                a=-z
        if 500-(y+25)<1:
            z=randrange(1,4)
            if (b<0):
                b=-z
            else:
                b=z
            b=-b
        elif y-25<1:
            b=-b
        time.sleep(.05)

main()
```

Comment: `time.sleep(.05)` will cause it to move really fast because that it less than a millisecond

Comment: It looks like you are using a margin of 25 pixels for the collision tests, but the radius of the ball is only 10. If you set them the same it should touch exactly: if the radius is 10 then it should bounce when the center is 10 away from the edges.

Comment: @samgak omgg..thank you so much!

Comment: @cricket_007 oh okayy thanks!